# insert proccess whith looping in php

Tags: php, insert

firstly sorry my english is bad
then
i have problem 
i try to make lopping insert into table but i have problem i can't make array for inputs 
to can  insert in table with looping from another table
maybe u can't understand me but look to the code and u will understand my problem

```
           $select = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table_name   ");
    ?>
    <form method="post" action="">
    <?
    while($row =mysql_fetch_array($select))
    {
          if($_POST['add'])
        {
    $updpol = mysql_query("insert into table_name2                             (yes,no,maybe,g_id)
values           
                 ('".$_POST['yes']."','".$_POST['no']."','".$_POST['maybe']."','".$row['id']."')
                                  ")
        }
          else{
    ?>
    <input type="checkbox" name="yes" value="1" /> 
    <br />
    <input type="checkbox" name="no" value="1" />
    <br />
    <input type="checkbox" name="maybe" value="1" /> 

    <?


    }
    ?>
    <input type="submit" name="add_poll" value="submit"  />
    </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

in your php code , your checking if:

```
if($_POST['add'])
```

While there's no input named `add` in your form.
I believe you meant:

```
if($_POST['add_poll'])
```

In order to have multiply instances of inputs , you can do something like:

```
   <input type="checkbox" name="yes[]" value="1" /> 
    <br />
    <input type="checkbox" name="no[]" value="1" />
    <br />
    <input type="checkbox" name="maybe[]" value="1" />
```

So , now , when posted:

`$_POST['yes']` is an array of all the checkboxes.
And as an array , it starts with `$_POST['yes'][0]` and continues `$_POST['yes'][1]` and so on.

Therefore:

```
           $select = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table_name   ");
    ?>
    <form method="post" action="">
    <?
    $i = 0;
    while($row =mysql_fetch_array($select))
    {
          if($_POST['add_poll'])
        {
    $updpol = mysql_query("insert into table_name2                             (yes,no,maybe,g_id)
values           
                 ('".$_POST['yes'][$i]."','".$_POST['no'][$i]."','".$_POST['maybe'][$i]."','".$row['id']."')
                                  ");
        $i++;
        }
          else{
    ?>
    <input type="checkbox" name="yes[]" value="1" /> 
    <br />
    <input type="checkbox" name="no[]" value="1" />
    <br />
    <input type="checkbox" name="maybe[]" value="1" /> 

    <?


    }
    ?>
    <input type="submit" name="add_poll" value="submit"  />
    </form>
```

Comment: i was edit my code with ur code but the problem still because when i was submit there was one row take all values this is the sql                                                                  >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>     
id  yes  no  maybe  g_id
537  0  0  0  6
536  1  0  0  5 
535  1  1  1  4 
538  0  0  0  7

Comment: this is the link of the image from mysql because i can't insert this here open the link http://www.dr-web2.com/problem.jpg

Comment: I don't get the problem , my friend.